# Do comment upvotes affect your rep?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

When your comment is upvoted, does it increase your reputation or does it not have any effect on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It does not affect your rep at all.  But, you can get badges for upvoted comments:

> **[Commentator](https://superuser.com/badges/31/commentator)**: Left 10 comments.

and

> **[Pundit](https://superuser.com/badges/40/pundit)** Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

Comment: Any specific reason why it's that way? Seems like it would make sense to increase the reputation of the user if they have a good comment.

Comment: Comments are supposed to be weightless for the most part, for discussion and clarification purposes.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for your comment clarifying that. :)

Comment: no problem @ThiagoM. :)

Comment: I could have sworn you used to get +2 rep for each comment... Another site maybe?

Comment: @Luke nope. Never has happened, never will. I think you're thinking of th +2 rep you get when you accept an answer.

Comment: @studiohack Might have been. But I do understand why they shouldn't be worth rep, but I think they should after say, +5 votes or +10