# Why don't up-votes on comments give reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, votes, up-votes

I've recently seen a few up-votes on my **comments** on some answers/posts/questions. However, I've noticed that I never received any reputation from them.

Why is it that we don't receive reputation from up-votes on comments? Or do you get reputation when 10, or 20, people vote up a comment?

Comment: Are designed to be temporary not permanent.  If you want reputation post full detailed and high-quality answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do comment upvotes affect your rep?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2596/do-comment-upvotes-affect-your-rep)

Comment: Technically, the proposed dupe asks does it, and this one asks why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comments serve an auxiliary function; they exist to support the all-important questions and answers. The goal is not to generate more comments, but better Q&A.

As such, you should assume that comments will be temporary; if you're putting information into a comment that would be nice to have around long-term, consider trying to work it into the question or an answer instead.

Granting reputation for comment votes would create a perverse incentive to post more of them and keep them around longer, potentially resulting in situations where questions and answers are buried under scores of kibitzing comments - the sorry state so many forums find themselves in.

Also, we'd probably have to implement downvotes.